# Adding dots before 1st, 2nd, 3th and 4th names, but only first letter

Tags: excel, vba

*Firstly sorry for my bad English it isn't my first language.*

I recently got this adjusted code from another user (thanks so much)

```
Sub AddDotAfter()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = Left$(cell.Value, 1) & "."
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Now, this code gets the first letter of a name a puts it into another column with a dot after the letter, for example, `D.`

Now I'm looking to do the same thing inside this code but with people who have more names.

So what I want is if someone's name is `David Charles James Jordan`, I would like the script to get the first letter of those names and put a dot after it, for example, `D. C. J. J.`

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should the letters(+dot) be all in the same cell?  Or each letter(+dot) in a different cell?  Must it be VBA or can you use formulas or Power Query.  Which version of Excel? (windows / Mac / year)?

Comment: They should be in the same cell. it must be in VBA Excel, Excel version Office 365 and for Windows 10, 2004 build.

Thanks for your time Ron!

Comment: So if the name in cell C1 is Chanel Dave Charles Jordan, cell B1 must be C. D. C. J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace the part of your routine that only looks at the beginning, to look at all of the words and construct a string.

eg:

***Edit** to show dot after last letter*

```
        S = ""
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            V = Split(cell.Value, " ")
        For Each W In V
            S = S & Left$(W, 1) & "."
        Next W
        
        cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value = S
        
        End If
```

[image]

Comment: It says object required?

Comment: @GenjutsuGhost With no context, that information is not helpful.  I cannot see your screen.

Comment: Sorry, it seems to work, but 2 things, for some reason its ads a blank space before the first letter, and also the 4th letter doesn't get a dot.

Comment: For the last dot, see my edit.  For the preceding space, check your data.

Comment: This is the output I get now: C.D.C.J is it possible to make it C. D. C. J.  ?

Comment: @GenjutsuGhost You should be able to modify the code for that.  What line do you think you'd have to change?

Comment: Hi Ron you are a true genius, I got it working now thanks so much!

The output now is C.D.C.J. I checked I don't need the spaces after each letter!

Again ty so much!